# How to read a data from text file and store it in CSV without overriding it pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have text files which contain random data(no of lines are also different). I want to read it in such a way that the first line is store in first row of CSV file and second line on second row and so on. if rows finish and if data is left it can add a comma(,) and start storing again.

```
def round():
    cli = int(input('no of rows:: '))
    df_round_robin = self.path_to_csv.head(cli)
    df_round_robin.assign(new_column='0')
    queue = []
    fileloaction = "C:\Users\pro\.....*"
    for filename in os.listdir(filelocation):
        complete_path = filelocation + filename
        f = open(complete_path, "r")
        for i in f:
            queue.append(i)
        for i in queue:
            df_round_robin["new_column"] = i
            df_round_robin.to_csv(f'{filename}_round.csv')
            print(df_round_robin)
        quit()
```

now this function which i wrote is working but not like what I want it always override data and also all rows contain same data.

this is what i want. but can't get it

```
if cli = 2
file contain four line
1
2
3 
4

row1  row2  row3 new_column
1      2     3      1,3  or [1,3] # or list anything but in this form
1      2     3      2,4


if cli = 2
file contain five line
1
2
3 
4
5

row1  row2  row3 new_column
1      2     3      1,3,5
1      2     3      2,4
```

Comment: it looks like this function is extracted from a class as it refers to `self` and the indent is 8 spaces. There are undefined variables such as `cli` and `filelocation`. The question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @D.L Hi sorry for the mistake I remove it did not check it will helpfull now you can check it. I edit it. it will be great if I get some help stuck in this issue for very long time

Comment: Pandas uses "w" (write) mode by default, and that will overwrite the existing file. To add to an existing file, use `df_round_robin.to_csv(f'{filename}_round.csv', mode='a')`

Comment: @tdelaney **mode='a'** add same data though out the rows. secon. it merge all files. e.g. **1.csv data is also avalible in 2.csv file and so on**